# Store variabe against each JSON object in a list using Dataweave

Tags: json, mule, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I am mapping a list of JSON objects from a database to an other list of JSON objects using Dataweave and Transform Message in Anypoint Studio 6.1.1 and Mule 3.8.1.

There are a couple of fields in the input list of JSONs that do not have a mapping in the new output and I want to use the values later in the processing but do not want them to be outputted at the end.

Is there a way I can assign a variable (which will be different) for each JSON object in the output link and then reference it later in the flow?

I just want to see if I can reduce processing time by not having to process one object at a time through Dataweave.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create another output, besides just Payload in Anypoint Studio. See the following:

[image]